# Can rpath value be a symbolic link?

Tags: linker, rpath

In makefile I'm passing rpath to the linker like this

```
-Wl,-rpath,/absolute_path_to_folder_with_lib
```

Everything works, but when I do

```
-Wl,-rpath,~/symlink
```

Where
~/symlink -> /absolute_path_to_folder_with_lib
The library is not loaded 
Can value of rpath be a symbolic link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can value of rpath be a symbolic link?

It sure can, but you misunderstood your problem, which is not about symbolic link, but about `~` expansion.

When you link your binary with `-Wl,-rpath,~/symlink`, you end up with `RPATH` that is *literally* `~/symlink`. Such a directory (or a symlink) does not exist.

When you type e.g. `ls ~/symlink` into your shell, what actually happens is that your shell expands `~` to whatever `$HOME` is set to, and then  does a `readdir` on the *expanded* result.

But dynamic linker does not perform any such expansion, and literally looks for `./~/symlink`, which of course doesn't exist.

What you want then is: `-Wl,-rpath,$HOME/symlink`.